# How to backup home folder using dump?

Tags: ubuntu, dump

I want to backup my home folder using `dump` but I have some trouble. If I try to use the -u option , I get this message:

```
 DUMP: You can't update the dumpdates file when dumping a subdirectory
```

So I remove the -u option and I make an level 0 dump. But if I try to do a level 1 backupI get this error:

```
DUMP: Only level 0 dumps are allowed on a subdirectory
```

What can I do? If I can only do level 0 dumps with `dump`, it's useless for me.
Is there an alternative?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`rsnapshot`](http://www.rsnapshot.org/), [`obnam`](http://liw.fi/obnam/), [`duplicity`](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/), or [`rdiff-backup`](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/) to create backups.

Don't use `dump` – it works by reading the disk directly and parsing the filesystem itself; it's just not going to work with subdirectories, nor with filesystems other than ext3.